# Зависание linux-системы при подключении usb-микрофона

Tags: usb, linux

Есть две виртуальные машины, на одной стоит Linux Mint 14 x64, на другой Debian Squeeze x64. Для виртуализации использую программу VirtualBox. Сами гостевые системы рабочие. Но когда пытаюсь подключить usb-микрофон Logitech (AK5370 - так его определяет lsusb), то Mint повисает сразу. В Debian-e микрофон вроде определяется.

Вот что показывает $ cat /proc/asound/cards :

```
 0 [I82801AAICH    ]: ICH - Intel 82801AA-ICH                      Intel 82801AA-ICH with STAC9700,83,84 at irq 21 1 [default        ]: USB-Audio - AK5370                                AKM              AK5370           at usb-0000:00:06.0-2, full speed
```

Результат $ arecord --list-devices:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 0: Intel ICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH]  Subdevices: 1/1  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0card 0: I82801AAICH [Intel 82801AA-ICH], device 1: Intel ICH - MIC ADC [Intel 82801AA-ICH - MIC ADC]  Subdevices: 1/1  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0card 1: default [AK5370          ], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]  Subdevices: 1/1  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Но он не работает. При этом если в программе Audacity в настройках напрямую указать этот микрофон как записывающее устройство, то при старте записи система намертво повисает.

Я пробовал все советы из этой статьи:http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/USB_mic_on_Linux

Ничего не помогло, но, я не силен в администрировании linux-систем, поэтому мог что-то упустить.

Буду рад любой подсказке :)

P.S.: хостовая система - Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1):

начнем с VB.
VB с поддержкой USB (полную версию) можно скачать только с официального репозитория. Вам, как предполагаю, нужен для Win. 
Соответственно для гостевых систем требуется свой VBoxLinuxAdditions - он установлен?

Comment: Да, установлен.

Comment: Попробуйте иструкции [отсюда](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=199348.0) и [отсюда](http://sudo.in/node/131)

Comment: @Justicet, не помогло. Те же зависания. Сдается мне, что дело в самом VirtualBox.